# In Solr. I want it to concatenate words in the search query

Tags: search, solr, concatenation

For example,when black white pink table is searched by the user then black white pink table, blackwhitepink table should be searched. Only 3 word phase should be treated as one token

Comment: What if `table black white pink` is searched? What about `white pink table`?

Comment: Then again we should have search results for table blackwhitepink or table black white pink. A realistic example would be a user searching for Cisco 1gbps router so you would have search results for Cisco 1gbpsrouter and cisco 1 gbps router.

Comment: So what kind of rule set do you have for not including `cisco` into that combination? If it doesn't really matter that you also search for `cisco1gpsrouter` (in addition to the other terms), you can use the [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/filter-descriptions.html#shingle-filter).

Comment: So i want to give the users more precise results when they search for a brand with a product. So shingleFilter would not trigger incorrect combinations

Comment: The problem with using a shingle filter is that the _sequence_ of the tokens becomes relevant. I.e. if you've indexed `foo bar` as `foobar`, someone searching for `bar foo` won't give a hit. However, as an additional field that gives a boost for hits where the "sequence" of words is correct, it'd probably work fine.